# Using Table Variables with xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a flat text file using a query that concatenates multiple values from multiple tables.  This result set is being inserted into a table variable which I would like to use in the xp_cmdshell call to create the text file.  Here's a sample of my code.

```
DECLARE @tablevar table (string nvarchar(200))

INSERT INTO @tablevar
SELECT 'test' + column1 + column2
FROM SampleTable

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM @tablevar" queryout "C:\temp\output.txt" -T -c '
```

I get the following error when I make the xp_cmdshell call:

> SQLState = 42000, NativeError = 1087
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Must declare the table variable "@outputtable".
>   SQLState = 42000, NativeError = 8180
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   NULL

When attempting to use a temp table use this code

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Select * From #temp" queryout "C:\temp\outputtable.txt" -T -c '
```

I get this error message

> SQLState = 42S02, NativeError = 208
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'tempdb.temp'.
>   SQLState = 42000, NativeError = 8180
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Is using a temp table or table variable with xp_cmdshell just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@table` variable and `#temp` table are both out of scope to other connections, but global temp tables like `##my_global_temp` should work.